# Remote Build ERROR on OPENSHIFT

Tags: maven, openshift

Using **OpenShift v2**, when I start the **remote** build and deploy via "**git push**" command, I have this strange build problem that blocks the deploy of my application on the Application Server cartridge (wildfly10):

```
remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project myproject:myproject:war:1.0: 
Failure to find com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.0 in
http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/groups/public 
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed 
or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

It seems that the remote build process (by maven) don't find "*javax.mail*" library on OpenShift repository.

Is it correct my opinion?

On my project pom I have only this base dependecy:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is timely and helpful. I was able to force an update and resolve this issue by deleting the invalid locally cached dependency in ~/.m2/repository/path/to/your/dependency on OpenShift, and then initiating another git push to trigger maven build.

Comment: Thank you George, but after trying your solution I still have the same build problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I tried this and it worked for me:

**Create an empty file called force_clean_build inside application .openshift/markers directory. Commit the file and push the changes. This will remove the .m2 repository and download all the dependencies and plugins again.**